# call methods on akka actors in scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a an actor defined as so:

```
class nodeActor(ID: String) extends Actor
```

which contains a method, which is used to set up the actor before it is started:

```
def addRef(actor:ActorRef)
```

I instantiate this actor as so:

```
val node1 = system.actorOf(Props(new nodeActor("node1")), name="node1")
```

which returns me an ActorRef. The compiler doesn't let me call "addRef" on an ActorRef since it's a member of the subtype. So I cast the node using:

```
node1.asInstanceOf[nodeActor].addRef(link1)
```

Which keeps the compiler happy. Then at runtime I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.actor.LocalActorRef cannot be cast to ActorStressTest.nodeActor
```

which doesn't even seem to make sense to me since it's a subtype and I should be able to cast to it.

Ideas?

Comment: Please communicate with an actor by sending messages, not by direct method call. Those who implement actors work hard to hide real actor instance behind ActorReferences. It is a different programming model. Get used to it.

Comment: in general "it's a subtype..I should be able to cast to it" is a dangerous assertion. you can cast a reference to a subtype if and only if the referent conforms to that subtype, which is not in general true, and which apparently is not true in your case.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I heartily suggest you to carefully read the [documentation](http://akka.io/docs/) before venturing further. It will probably help you avoid many pitfalls and a lot of pointless work. Sincerely.

Comment: "it's a subtype..I should be able to cast to it" - this is not even true: `node1` is an `ActorRef`, which acts like a pointer to an actual Actor instance. Your `nodeActor` instance is hidden away in the Akka system, and isn't meant to be interacted with directly.

Comment: @Dylan Ok so that seems to be where my problem lies. I thought that an  ActorRef, since it was being returned by a constructor-type-thing was the actual actor object, not just a pointer in to the system. Makes sense now ta.

Comment: @pagoda_5b I spent several hours on the akka documentation before posting here. As dylan has pointed out, my problem was an incorrect mental model of a concept, which is rarely solved by large amounts of RTFM.

Comment: @Alex I didn't meant to say you didn't read the docs or you've been lazy, sorry if it sounded so. Often for me the best help to get a grip on the design and usage of frameworks like this is to read the [google mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/akka-user) (lots of good insights from there!) and to seek for video material like [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Introducing-Akka) or [here](http://vimeo.com/50400591). Have fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to call an actor's methods directly from another class. It breaks the whole design of the system, which is

- to encapsulate the actor's specific implementation by communicating only with the `ActorRef` obtained with the call to `actorOf` or `actorFor`
- to limit communication between actors to message passing, using the available (`!`, `?`) methods

If you need to create a reference in `ActorA` to another `ActorB` you can:

- Create the ref to `ActorB` in the `ActorA`'s initialization code as shown in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/actors.html
- Send the `ActorB`'s reference to the `ActorA` as a specific message. Then `ActorA` can store the reference within `receive` implementation

If you need to call a method to satisfy an Interface/Trait constraint, have a look at [Typed Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/typed-actors.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll refactor my code to keep this in mind. I knew that you were meant to use message passing but I didn't know that you are actively stopped form using method calls to set things up. Anyway, thanks again, answer accepted.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this for testing then when creating actor you can just do this:

```
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
val actorRef = TestActorRef[MyActor]
val actor = actorRef.underlyingActor
```

Then you can run methods on actor

Comment: Very helpful answer for me. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can cast anything to anything and the compiler will happily do so, but the check at runtime will fail if it's not possible. The `ActorRef` is not an instance of your `Actor` class or a subtype of it.

When you do this:

```
system.actorOf(Props(new nodeActor("node1")), name="node1")
```

You get back an `ActorRef` to which you should only send messages. Apart from that, the actor is started immediately when you call `system.actorOf`, so trying to call a method on the `Actor` instance before it is started is not possible.

Here is a description of actors from the [Akka Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/actors.html) explaining actor references.