# Scala stackoverflowexception - Possible cyclic dependency?

Tags: scala, linked-list, stack-overflow

I have the following implementation for class

```
class User(identifier : Int, actor : ActorRef) extends Serializable {
  var userName : String = Random.alphanumeric.take(4 + Random.nextInt(12)).mkString
  var msgRate : Int = 0
  var followers : MutableList[User] = new MutableList[User]()
  var messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[String](Messages.maxBufferSize)

  override def equals(o : Any) = o match {
    case that : User => that.userName.equals(this.userName)
    case _ => false

  }

  override def hashCode = identifier.hashCode    

  def getRecentMessages(n : Int) : List[String] = {
    var msgList : List[String] = List.empty[String]
    msgList = messageQueue.toArray().toList.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
    return msgList
  }


  def isFollowing(user : User) : Boolean = {
    user.getFollowers().contains(this)
  }

  def isFollowed(user : User) : Boolean = {
      followers.contains(user)
  }

  def getFollowers() : MutableList[User] = {
    return followers
  }

  def addFollower(follower : User) {
    followers += follower
  }

}
```

When I run for a smaller set of actors, adding follower does not cause any problem and the code runs fine. However, for a large number of actors the issue arises:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at akka.actor.SerializedActorRef$.apply(ActorRef.scala:420)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.writeReplace(ActorRef.scala:389)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1075)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
```

Is this a case of using the same User instance within the class in the form of followers?
Is there a resolution to this problem?

EDIT:
Including more code as per request. Sorry about a very large code base. Let me give some brief explanation about this. I am working on a message simulator similar to twitter where I have to manage messages based on user tagging. The client randomly generates the userbase, sends messages at a rate and sender manages the data.

Initial handshake comprises of sending the entire client information from Interactor(). Server acknowledges each client and then this is scheduled regularly. The issue arises when sending the entire client information that results in stackoverflow exception. In the code the issue arises at the end of Init in Interactor()

Here is the code:

```
object ClientApp extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("TwitterClientActor", ConfigFactory.load("applicationClient.conf"))
  val sActor = system.actorFor("akka.tcp://ServerActor@" + ipAddr + "/user/Server")
  val serverVector = Vector.fill(Messages.nServers)(sActor)
  val serverActor = system.actorOf(Props.empty.withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(routees = serverVector)), "serverRouter")
  val interActor = system.actorOf(Props(new Interactor()))
  var nRequests : Int = 0
  val startTime = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
  interActor ! Init

}

// Intermediate manager system
class Interactor() extends Actor {
  // Member definitions
  import actorSys.dispatcher

  // User list
  for (i <- 0 to clientList.length - 1)
    clientList(i) = new User(i, context.actorOf(Props(new Client(i : Int))))
  readFollowersStats(clientList.length)

  def receive = {

    // Send request to users
    case Init =>
      for (curUser <- clientList)
        serverActor ! RegisterClients(curUser)
    // ISSUE IMMEDIATELY AFTER THIS

    // Schedule after request
    case ScheduleClient(identifier) =>
      if (!limitReached) {
        val curUser = clientList(identifier)
        val cancellable = actorSys.scheduler.schedule(0.milliseconds, curUser.getMsgRate.milliseconds)(sendMsg(curUser))
        cancelMap += (curUser -> cancellable)
      }

    case ClientCompleted =>
      nCompleted += 1
      if (nCompleted == clientList.length) {
            serverActor ! Broadcast(PoisonPill)
            context.system.shutdown()
        }
  }

  def sendMsg(curUser : User) = {
    nMessages.incrementAndGet()

    if (nMessages.get() == Messages.msgLimit) {
      println("Limit reached!")
      limitReached = true
      for (cancellable <- cancelMap.values)
        cancellable.cancel()
    }
    else if (nMessages.get() < Messages.msgLimit) {
      println(nMessages)
      val curSec = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
      val curTime = ((curSec - ClientApp.startTime).toDouble) / 1000
      if (curTime >= Messages.peakStart && curTime < Messages.peakEnd) {
        for (i <- 0 to Messages.peakScale) {
          var rndTweet = randomTweet(curUser)
          curUser.getReference() ! Tweet(rndTweet)
        }
        nMessages.addAndGet(Messages.peakScale - 1)
      }
      else {
        var rndTweet = randomTweet(curUser)
        //println(curUser + " ---> " + rndTweet)
        curUser.getReference() ! Tweet(rndTweet)
      }
    }
  }

  def randomTweet(curUser : User) : String = {
    // Return some random string
  }

  def readFollowersStats(usersCount : Int) {
    // Read the file stats of the format, min-max percentage
        while(file is not empty)
      FollowersGeneration(usersCount, minFollowers.toInt, maxFollowers.toInt, percentage.toDouble)
    }

  }

  def FollowersGeneration(usersCount : Int, minFollowers : Int, maxFollowers : Int, followersPercentage : Double) {

    var noOfFollowers : Int = 0
    var users : Double = (followersPercentage / 100) * usersCount
    var temp : Int = users.toInt
    for (i <- 0 until temp) {
        if (minFollowers < usersCount) {
            // Random follower assignment...
            // CODE ACCESSES FOLLOWERS HERE!!!
            if (!user.isFollowed(clientList(id)))
                user.addFollower(clientList(id))
          }
        }
    }

}

class Client(identifier : Int) extends Actor {
  var serverActor = ClientApp.serverActor
  def receive = {

    case "ACK" =>
      println("Client " + identifier + " activated")
      ClientApp.interActor ! ScheduleClient(identifier)

    case Tweet(tweet) =>
      serverActor ! Tweet(tweet)

      // Other functions


  }

}
```

**EDIT2 : Explanation about the use case**

This is a Client-Server model. 
Client: Initiator object creates a Broker class. The broker class creates a list of user actors (Class User in this case) and establishes a relationship between different users, i.e. assigning random followers, rate and other properties. Now, the entire list of users are sent to the server where the server activates the individual clients to start messaging. The client now sends random messages to server for which the server processes them.

The initial approach consisted of using a class User as above and then store the actorRef as a member in the class and send it to user. This was the issue and I changed the User list as an actor class. I have to generate followers and send it to server. I communicated the broker class to add the followers using messages. Now, issue arises from a programmatic perspective where at the server side, I have to access the followers of the User actor. I can either send message requesting the user '!' or use '?' to get the futures. This is the issue where this will slow down the processing capabilities of server. Are there more elegant approaches where I can access the member of the actorRef or much better solution where I can call a function?

Comment: It's not clear how exactly you invoke it, can you provide some code? The problem might be in a different place because there is some serialization seems to be going on.

Comment: I think you need to revisit your design. Your user class is NOT an actor but it contains "mutable" state and you are passing an ActorRef to it. I've not gone through rest of your code, but if you can explain why you User is not an Actor.

Comment: I agree with @SoumyaSimanta - the design is not very clear to me. I think you can simplify it using existing Akka features. However, start from fixing this line: `context.actorOf(Props(new Client(i : Int)))`. You should not create actors with constructors like that. See this doc: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html ("Dangerous Variants"). Maybe that's causing the problem. Anyway, try to push mutable state into an actor, not a message. It's also not clear where `RegisterClients` is handled.

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta The problem for a separate class instead of actor is the need for equals and hashcode implementations for collections of User class. If I had used User extends actor, I will not be able to use List.contains(User).

Comment: @dmachop - 1. I don't see why you cannot use List.contains(User) even if User is an Actor (extends Actor). 2. Why do you want to check contains on a User object, why not just keep track of all unique Users (using an unique id) inside an actor and then ask the Actor to tell if the user is unique or not. The Actor itself can store the user ids inside an in memory off heap cache or keep it in a persistent store or do both.

Comment: @Soumya Simanta I understand that I can maintain an identifier and use it as a list. That is not the issue. If I wrap the given class as an actor, is there a way that I can call the function as a normal class? I guess this will break the agreement which tightly couples actor and its properties. Yes, the actor is mutable. My need is that I should be able to access the actorRef with the methods and members that I have defined in it. I've given a sample use case that I'm currently working on where this seems to be an issue.

Comment: @dmachop - In your design you should map actors to your classes and then send messages between them to get things done in a async and concurrent way. If you keep an ActorRef inside a normal Scala class (User in your case) and you have mutable state inside your User class you will run into concurrency problem unless you make sure you are keeping  your state threadsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is an example of bad practice to wrap an actor inside a class. Ensure that the actor model is utilized instead of approaching it from an object oriented perspective.

In the above scenario, the structure to be defined is:

```
Broker -> UserActor -> User
```

Broker has a map  and this can be used to resolve any dependencies with it. The model ensures that the actor model is separated from the object logic. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293167/3003393)

Another alternative is to utilize [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#futures-scala). [This link](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html) is a great place to start.